# SQL self join multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2000

I have a single database table that stores week entries.

```
Id        Value     WeekId
1         1.0000    1
2         2.0000    1
```

There can be up to three entries with the same week.

So I figured using a self join would solve this

```
SELECT w1.Value, w2.Value, w3.Value 
FROM [List].[dbo].[testWeekEntries] as w1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [List].[dbo].[testWeekEntries] as w2 ON w1.WeekId = w2.weekId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [List].[dbo].[testWeekEntries] as w3 ON w2.WeekId = w3.WeekId 
WHERE w1.Id < w2.Id AND w2.Id < w3.Id
```

The problem: It worls fine with the maximum number of entries however it doesn't pull back a row with one or two entries.

Is there a different type of join I can use to pull back a row with only one or two entries or a different way of approaching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These entries are not returning because your `WHERE` clause explicitly filters them out when the joined tables return `NULL` values.

This solution adds a sequential rownumber to each record, restarting to 1 for each week. This allows you to use this sequential number in a PIVOT statement

**SQL 2000 Statement**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  (SELECT  COUNT(*) 
                   FROM    testWeekEntries 
                   WHERE   Id <= we.Id 
                           AND WeekId = we.WeekId) as rn
                  , Value
                  , WeekId
          FROM    testWeekEntries we
        ) q
PIVOT   (MAX(Value) FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) AS PVT
```

**SQL 2008 Statement**

```
;WITH q AS (
SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WeekId ORDER BY Id)
        , Id
        , Value
        , WeekId
FROM    [testWeekEntries] as w1 
)
SELECT  Value
        , (SELECT Value FROM q q1 WHERE q1.rn = q.rn + 1 AND q1.WeekId = q.WeekId)
        , (SELECT Value FROM q q2 WHERE q2.rn = q.rn + 2 AND q2.WeekId = q.WeekId)
FROM    q
WHERE   q.rn = 1
```

Comment: I tried this however it now brings back multiple rows where it should only bring back one row per week Id

Comment: @user900566 - you are right, my mistake. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @user900566 - I have adjusted the answer to adres the bug.

Comment: @user900566 - to be honest, I have this nagging feeling it can be simplified but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: just realised that the productino server is ms sql 2000 and doesnt have row_number() functionality

Comment: @user900566 - I have added a SQL Server 2000 solution

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add in your where clause the possibility that `w2.Id is null` or `w3.id is null`

So something like

```
WHERE 
  (w2.Id is null and w3.id is null) or 
  (w3.id is null and w1.id < w2.id) or 
  (w1.id < w2.id and w2.id < w3.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `PIVOT`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Value,
       WeekId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WeekId ORDER BY Id) AS RN
FROM   [List].[dbo].[testWeekEntries]       
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) AS PVT
```

Comment: +1 Thx Martin, PIVOT is still not my cup of tea but I have to ask: isn't there an easier solution to this without resorting to a CTE  and adding a ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @Lieven - Not that I can think of!

Comment: You have no idea how comforting that is for me <vbg>.